# What is scipy's equivalent to matlab's `mle` function?

Tags: python, matlab, scipy, mathematical-optimization

I'm trying to fit some data to a mixed model using an [expectation maximization approach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expectation%E2%80%93maximization_algorithm).  In Matlab, the code is as follows

```
% mixture model's PDF
mixtureModel = ...
    @(x,pguess,kappa) pguess/180 + (1-pguess)*exp(kappa*cos(2*x/180*pi))/(180*besseli(0,kappa));

% Set up parameters for the MLE function
options = statset('mlecustom');
options.MaxIter     = 20000;
options.MaxFunEvals = 20000;

% fit the model using maximum likelihood estimate
params = mle(data, 'pdf', mixtureModel, 'start', [.1 1/10], ...
            'lowerbound', [0 1/50], 'upperbound', [1 50], ...
            'options', options);
```

The `data` parameter is a 1-D vector of floats.

I'm wondering how the equivalent computation can be achieved in Python.  I looked into `scipy.optimize.minimize`, but this doesn't seem to be a drop-in replacement for Matlab's `mle`.

I'm a bit lost and overwhelmed, can somebody point me in the right direction (ideally with some example code?)

Thanks very much in advance!

**Edit:** In the meantime I've found [this](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/tritemio/notebooks/blob/master/Mixture_Model_Fitting.ipynb), but I'm still rather lost as (1) this seems primarily focused on mixed guassian models (which mine is not) and (2) my mathematical skills are severely lacking.  That said, I'll happily accept an answer that elucidates how this notebook relates to my specific problem!

Answer (score 1):

This is a mixture model (not mixed model) of uniform and von mises distributions whose parameters you are trying to infer using direct maximum likelihood estimation (not EM, although that may be more appropriate).  You can find theses written on this exact problem if you search on the internet. SciPy doesn't have anything that would be as clear a choice as matlab's fmincon which it uses as its default in your code, but you could look for scipy optimization methods that allow bounds on parameters.  The scipy interface is different from that of matlab's mle, and you will want to pass the data in the 'args' argument of the scipy minimization functions, whereas the pguess and kappa parameters will need to be represented by a parameter array of length 2.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the scikit-learn toolkit has what you need:

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.mixture.GMM.html.

> Gaussian Mixture Model
>
> Representation of a Gaussian mixture model probability distribution. This class allows for easy evaluation of, sampling from, and maximum-likelihood estimation of the parameters of a GMM distribution.
>
> Initializes parameters such that every mixture component has zero mean and identity covariance.